# post JSON object into specified div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, facebook

Trying to create a FAN area on facebook where I need to post all products available only to my facebook fans.

My php file creates plain HTML, which I would like to grab from Facebook end.

How this can be done if this can be done at all?

The following is entire content of my script.js file

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"https://www.mysite.com/includes/facebook_fan_page.php",
data: data,
dataType:"html",
error:function(){},
success:function(response){
    $('#products').html(response);
}
```

})

and here is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  [[style.css]]
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mysite.com/js/jquery-
1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  [[script.js]]
  </head>

<body>
<div class="content">

  <div id="products"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know how to write output in to the empty `div` that I have on my apps `index.html` page `<div id="products"></div>`

Also, the app I use on facebook is Static HTML iFrame Tabs, if it makes any difference

Please help

Thanks to you all in advance

My skills of ajax and js are very limited, so please be patient with me on this one.

Comment: can you show the json output??

Comment: the sucess function gets a response object?

Comment: @KartikA When I place the link https://www.mysite.com/includes/facebook_fan_page.php directly into my browser, I can see everything, but I cannot see it working with ajax request on facebook for some reason. In fact the output of JSON is plain html.

Comment: Yes I need to see that HTML

Comment: the ajax request seems to be fine but you need to add a variable in success callback that carries the data which will have the JSON object. Try this
document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML += response.field;

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this is the whole problem, since I have no idea how to do it. Would be helpful if you can put your suggestion in Answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see my answer..??? tell me if you find it useful :D

Answer (score 0):

This is also a method for Ajax Post request, I find it simple. Tell me if you find this useful

> In HTML Page
>
> In script file or  tag

```
$.POST("filename.php", data, function(response) {
    if(!response) {
      alert("Oh Snap! I hate this part"); 
    }
    else {
      $("#div").html(response.field);
    }
 });
```

> Read about his here [AJAX POST REQUEST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)